# DB2 Naming Standards - Similar to OFA

Tags: oracle, db2

I'm an Oracle DBA getting started on DB2.

On Oracle we have a document called [Optimal Flexible Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/app_ofa.htm) that sets a group of naming standards, like what should be the disk name for the database. This is a great because if everyone follows the document you can easily administer new databases without suffering.

I've installed a DB2 (next next finish way) and I noticed that the database is created on `/home/db2inst1` is this ok?

I was wondering if IBM provides some guide for that.

Comment: Just FYI db2inst1 is the default name for the first instance of DB2, should you not name your instance otherwise. All databases will create by default there unless you override the default path at the instance level and/or specify (a) new path(s). In our case, we never went with defaults (security reasons). We always created named instances in different locations. And we placed data, system data, logs, archive logs, and backups all on different file paths (we had SAN underneath so I couldn't tell you if the disk was truly different or not).

Comment: IBM does not provide such a guide. Typically an organization that uses DB2 has internal standards about database file placement.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAldrich so no patterns. Any recommendation to create a new pattern for my organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is easier to elaborate on in an answer than in a comment.....

We tended to install our instances to `/inst/<instance-name>`. I leave the instance naming scheme up to you. If you make it too similar than technically you have introduced a security risk as the instance names are eaiser to guess.

Then you could so something like the following:

```
/inst/<instance-name>/bkp
/inst/<instance-name>/offline
/inst/<instance-name>/online
/inst/<instance-name>/data
/inst/<instance-name>/dbdir
/inst/<instance-name>/logs
/inst/<instance-name>/archlogs
```

You can work with your server admins or your SAN admins or do the work yourself to decide which of these mounts is physically separate disk, LUNs, etc.

This is just something we did. We did it to provide separation of concerns of where the instance was installed, vs where the system tables vs the data tables, vs the logs, vs the archive logs, vs the backups. Whether or not it works for your organization, you will have to discuss.

Whatever you do, ***be consistent as much as is possible***.

Comment: I'll mark this as "correct answer" since was very helpful but I know that related to my question there is no correct answer.